# Best practice: checking backups of CMS-websites for viruses (code, database, and files)?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware

I've got backup files of several CMS-based websites on my local computer (Microsoft Windows) that need to get checked for viruses. Are there anti-virus scanners that catch viruses in the code, in files and in the database or will I have to take a different approach?

Comment: In the best case you would only backup data which does not contain code and restore a backup by installing the CMS again (document what plugins you need to install) and then import the data without any code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to deal with already made backup-archives.

Comment: Are you concerned about running malicious code on your server, or sending malicious responses to users from the websites?

Comment: I'm concerned that the shop owner, who regulary archives backups of the CMS on his local computer, may be in a false sense of security because the backups are infected already.